# Jboss throwing IllegalAccessError?

Tags: jboss, jax-rs

In my web project i am using below code

```
 response =  target.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).header(USERTOKEN, request.getTgtToken()).post(Entity.entity(request.getXmlObject(),MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE));
```

and its not creating any issue when deploying war into the local machine Jboss server. But when same war i am trying to run into server JBOSS machine ,i am end with the following exception

```
19:30:59,737 ERROR
 [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sure-admin-web].[Faces
 Servlet]] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for
 servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError:
 tried to access class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType$2 from class
 javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
         at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.<init>(MediaType.java:271) [javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar:2.1]
         at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.<init>(MediaType.java:262) [javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar:2.1]
         at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.<clinit>(MediaType.java:81) [javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.jar:2.1]
         at com.alu.ipprd.mdf.soa.portal.integration.restapi.MdoRestManagerImpl.fetchData(MdoRestManagerImpl.java:53)
 [mdf-portal-integration-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
         at com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.business.sure.TemplatesWorkOrder.processBusinessLogic(TemplatesWorkOrder.java:205)
 [mdf-portal-business-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
         at com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.business.sure.TemplatesWorkOrder.processBusinessLogic(TemplatesWorkOrder.java:77)
 [mdf-portal-business-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
         at com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.common.business.BaseWorkOrder.submitWorkOrder(BaseWorkOrder.java:75)
 [mdf-portal-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
         at com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.common.business.BaseWorkOrder.submitWorkOrder(BaseWorkOrder.java:34)
 [mdf-portal-common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
         at com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.bean.template.LinkCatalogCreateBean.fetchLinkSpecification(LinkCatalogCreateBean.java:2045)
 [classes:]
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_162]
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_162]
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_162]
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_162]
         at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:258) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
         at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
 [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
         at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
 [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
         at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128)
 [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
         at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2526)
 [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
         at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106)
 [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
         at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2166)
 [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
         at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2111)
 [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
         at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:289)
 [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
         at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247)
 [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
         at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107)
 [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
         at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
         at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
 [jsf-impl-2.1.28.redhat-8.jar:2.1.28.redhat-8]
         at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
 [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.28.Final-redhat-1]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
 [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
 [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
         at com.alu.ipprd.bsm.soa.portal.edgefilter.EdgeFilter.doFilter(EdgeFilter.java:29)
 [classes:]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
 [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
 [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
         at org.apache.catalina.core.Stand
```

Comment: The exception is thrown in `tried to access class javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType$2 from class
 javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType` but you did not tag it jax-rs but you did tag it JSF? Why? The JAX-RS is called from your code, not JSF. So please search correct the tagging.

Comment: Corrected the tagging